# Get part out of string

Tags: php

```
http://www.webpage.ee/xxx-galerii/event-02-02-13
```

How can i get "xxx" part out of that url using php? There is always "ee/" on the left side and "-galerii" on the right side.

Answer (score 4):

```
$path = parseurl($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
list($xxx) = explode('-', $path, 2);
```

Comment: instead of "xxx" i get "/xxx" when i echo $xxx

Comment: @kristjanzzz Then use `trim()` to remove the forward slash.

Comment: Yes, I forgot, that the leading slash is part of the url. `trim()` is the cleanest solution I guess (because theoretically there could be more than one slash), other solution is `substr($xxx, 1)`